# JSON Key cannot be same in Client and Server Side

Tags: javascript, java, json, browser

I have  rest api it gives some response `JSON data` .

For Example ,
  In my server side (JAVA) I am getting the below JSON Data

JSON Format Example (JAVA)

```
 {
"ShiftTemp" : "XXXX"
}
```

The Same response data I am getting like below in angular side (client side)

```
{
"shiftTemp":"xxxx"
}
```

`"ShiftTemp"` **(server)** and `"shiftTemp"` **(client)** . I am confusing why am i getting like the above diffferent cases JSON data . Please guide me am i need to add anything in my `MODEL` class in java or anything need to configure in my browser . I am using Server Side JAVA and front end using angularjs.

My model Java class

```
package com.Forcaste.domain.core;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.Document;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.TypeAlias;

import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.Field;


import java.io.Serializable;

import com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

@Document
@TypeAlias("Forecasting")
@ApiModel( value = "Forecasting", description = "Forecasting" )
public class Forecasting  implements Serializable  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ApiModelProperty( value = "The standard id attribute - System generated", required = true )
    @Id 

    private String Id;

    @ApiModelProperty( value = "ProductRelease", required = true )
    @Field
    private String ProductRelease;

    @Field
    @ApiModelProperty( value = "ContactSSExpDate", required = true )
    private String ContactSSExpDate;

    @ApiModelProperty( value = "created date", required = true )
    @Field
    private String Created_date;

    @ApiModelProperty( value = "Forecast_id", required = true )
    @Field
    private String Forecast_id;

    @ApiModelProperty( value = "created by value", required = true )
    @Field
    private long Created_by;


    @ApiModelProperty( value = "updated date", required = true )
    @Field
    private String Updated_date;


    @ApiModelProperty( value = "updated by value", required = true )
    @Field
    private long Updated_by;


    @ApiModelProperty( value = "Description", required = true )
    @Field
    private String LotusSeller_1;


    @ApiModelProperty( value = "Description", required = true )
    @Field
    private String Quarter;

    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setCreated_date(String Created_date) {
        this.Created_date = Created_date;
    }


    public String getCreated_date() {
        return Created_date;
    }

    public void setCreated_by(long Created_by) {
        this.Created_by = Created_by;
    }


    public long getCreated_by() {
        return Created_by;
    }

    public void setUpdated_date(String Updated_date) {
        this.Updated_date = Updated_date;
    }


    public String getUpdated_date() {
        return Updated_date;
    }

    public void setUpdated_by(long Updated_by) {
        this.Updated_by = Updated_by;
    }


    public long getUpdated_by() {
        return Updated_by;
    }



    public void setQuarter(String Quarter) {
        this.Quarter = Quarter;
    }


    public String getQuarter() {
        return Quarter;
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to say how you implement the REST server on the Java side. There are numerous ways to do so after all...

Comment: is it always just a capitalizing issue? if so, maybe you can just choose that keys will begin either with or without capital, and always convert them? (it is a workaround, yes)

Comment: Can you show us the code related to your java server and angular(client) about how you print that json output?

Comment: @HendraWD I added my above java  modal class .,

Comment: And my client side code is only a AJAX call using angularjs .@HendraWD

Comment: i don't see any "ShiftTemp" from your model

Comment: Above my java model class has a camel case order but i got those keywords i am gettting in browser side **cases** are different all the keywords starts with small and remaining letters are capital..,@HendraWD

Comment: Your right there is no **ShiftTemp** i took this as a example  ..@HendraWD

Comment: @mkl please give some suggestion about that problm ,.,, I pasted my java model class ..

Comment: On the client(angular), i suppose you get the data as a JSON string from server. Can you confirm that the output from your server(where you open from browser) is the same with `JSON.stringify(response.data)`?

Comment: @HendraWD I tried `JSON.stringify` but still same story ..

Comment: Please post the code from the server where you print out the response and post your client code, where you get the response. Because there is still too little information i got here, and i can't determine the problem